# Black & white movie or TV episode where a baby disappears from a highchair after bats fly past

Tags: story-identification, movie, tv

I’ve just stumbled here.  I’ve been searching all over to find a movie, or episode, based on keywords.  My details are vague as I was maybe 4-6 years old and only kinda remember one scene.

I would’ve seen this in years 1985? - 1986?  Guessing.

Black and white film.

Baby in highchair, in kitchen?

Woman/mother buzzing around, cleaning maybe? Feeding baby.

Bats fly through open windows, in one, straight out another.

Baby is gone from highchair, I think huge puddle of blood under chair.

That’s all I can recall. My mom doesn’t remember watching this.  I’ve looked through *The Twilight Zone* episodes, and *Alfred Hitchcock Presents* episodes.  I know no other references, so I may have run across it not realizing.

Any body have ideas?
Much appreciated!

Comment: Did you look at both the 1960-era Twilight Zone and the 1980s reboot?